# Xcode7.0 getting hanged everytime I try to run

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, xcode7

I downloaded fresh xcode7.0 from developer.apple.com
When I run the application. Its continuously getting hanged and force to quit. I restarted my mac thrice. uninstalled and again reinstalled Xcode7.0 and again restarted but problem is still there. Please suggest the solution.

Its Very frustrating...

Comment: Does this happen on a new blank project as well?

Comment: Do you have source control enabled?  I have found that the incidence of hangs is greater with more uncommitted changes on source control

Comment: I could not try with new blank project as it doesn't let me open the xcode itself. Its showing only Verifying "Xcode"... with progress bar which never gets completed.

Comment: what is your mac OS ver no

Comment: Its OS X Yosemite. Version 10.10.5

Comment: @Paulw11  No, its not under source control.

Comment: Hey Thanks All, I just removed all folders from ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Xcode.savedState and restarted xcode again. This worked for me.